# Dynamic HTML Component without Using any JS Library (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-routing

I have a Javascript function that fetch dynamic random recipes from `spoonacular` API and then append some HTML to an Element, the HTML includes dynamic links `HREFs`, if one is clicked it will go to dynamic route, such as `www.example.com/recipe/782585` (depends on the `ID` value)

```js
const spoonacular = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=c0c692d2b8be4e92a29883049789419b&includeNutrition=true.",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );

  const data = await response.json();

  data.results.forEach((e) => {
    const html = `
    <div class="dish" id="a${e.id}">
      <a href="recipe/${e.id}"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="dishImg" /></a>
      <h2 class="dishTitle">
        ${e.title}
      </h2>
  </div>
    `;
    dishes.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
  });
};

spoonacular();
```

the plan here is to make dynamic component `recipe.html` that will send request to `spoonacular` with the `ID` param and get informations about the recipe like ingredients and instructions..etc, now this looks easy using some JS libraries like `react`, but can I do that without using any Library or backend routing?

Comment: At the root, those UI libraries are built from plain javascript talking to the DOM, so yes, you can make the same DOM calls from javascript that those frameworks do. Not sure how routing comes into the problem, so maybe you need to be more specific about the issue you're asking about

Comment: in ```react``` we can make dynamic routes using react-router-dom, e.g. ```<Route path="/:component" element={<ComponentContainer />}></Route>``` then we can make ```Link``` to that route with dynamic parameter : ```<Link  to="/employees">``` , then we can use ```useParams``` to get the parameter value, i want to do the same thing but without using ```react```

Comment: if you want react stuff, then use react. If you want to see how react implements it, then you can look at the source. Fundamentally, you'll be storing some strings in some context (a javascript data model, or attached somewhere in the DOM)) and gluing them together to form URLs to fetch data. Libraries exist to give you higher-level abstractions than building everything from scratch, so if you want those abstractions, probably best to use the library rather than reinvent that wheel.